# Activity Diagram and Android Activity

Tags: android, uml, software-design

I was thinking about Activity Diagrams when a question arises in my mind, because they have the same name: should I design an Activity Diagram where all activities are only my android.Activity classes of my project? Or should diagram activities refer to low level user decisions, i.e. button clicks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not mess up with two different things only because they have similar names.

From the [oficial android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html): An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram): Activity diagrams are graphical representations of workflows of stepwise activities and actions with support for choice, iteration and concurrency. In the Unified Modeling Language, activity diagrams are intended to model both computational and organisational processes (i.e. workflows). Activity diagrams show the overall flow of control.

Yes, you can use activity diagrams to model your android activities interaction flow. You can even use an activity diagram to model only a single android activity, if this is a complex activity. It is up to you to decide where and how to use Activity diagrams, but they are not related to android activities because of the name by definition.